# how to configure jbpm 6 with jboss AS 7.1.1 and unable to open jbpm-console.

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

While installation of jbpm 6 it is downloading Jboss wildfly 8.1.0 but i dont want this already i installed Jboss AS 7.1.1
so can i change the jboss server wildfly 8.1.0 to Jboss AS 7.1.1 while installation of jbpm?

build.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Under the jbpm installer build.properties file will be present.

By default jboss wildfly server config enabled. if you want have jboss 7.1.1 as server uncomment the conguration for jboss 7 and comment the wildfly config and run the jbpm installer now the jboss 7.1.1 will be downloaded.